# Academic degrees in forms

Tags: input-fields, labels, copywriting

What form field labels tend to be used for pre-nominal and post-nominal academic titles in forms? Is e.g. "prenominal academic degree" used or is that too formal?

Comment: Is the audience for the form specifically academic, or of a more general nature?

Comment: @Izquierdo it's students, but of all kinds (from elementary school to university)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've often seen this labeled "Title" / "Name" / "Suffix" where Title and Suffix are collected via a select menu of predefined options.

For example, American Airlines includes a Title select menu containing MR., MRS., MS., MISS, MX., DR., and MASTER, as well as a Suffix select menu containing JR., SR., M.D., II, III, IV, V, and PH.D..

> [image: American Airlines profile settings, including Title, Name, and Suffix]
> *(Values have been obscured in the image)*

---

To address the specific case of only seeking academic titles rather than others that show other modifiers as well, it looks like there are a few terms for these.

There are a couple entries in Wikipedia for [prenominal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pre-nominal_letters) and [postnominal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post-nominal_letters) letters. I'm seeing usage for both terms spelled with and without the hyphen, and both terms phrased as **-nominal letters*, *titles*, or simply as a noun (e.g. *post-nominals*).

My assumption is that those who carry these modifiers will likely be familiar with these terms and would probably not be confused by seeing "Prenominal title" and "Post-nominals" (my impression of the two most common embodiments, but take your pick). If you worry that these terms may still cause your users pause, you can add a tooltip description next to the label as to what is intended for each blank, with examples.

Comment: Thing is, I'm dealing with blank input fields for both a prefix and a suffix and it should ideally be clear that the fields are for academic titles only. "Prefix" and "Suffix" is perhaps too general? But "Academic prefix" or "Academic titles (prefix)" don't sound right to me.

Comment: @TinMan Edited to address collecting only academic titles, not just any title.